# Summation of Output

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this code for calculating the marks in an exam which, of course, includes buttons!!

```js
function wrong_answer() {
  var calc = 0;
  var calc2 = 1;
  var div_ele = document.createElement("div");
  div_ele.innerHTML = calc - calc2;
  document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(div_ele);
}
function correct_answer() {
  var calc = 0;
  var calc2 = -3;
  var div_ele = document.createElement("div");
  div_ele.innerHTML = calc - calc2;
  document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(div_ele);
}
```

```css
 .div_wrong {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: red;
     font-weight: 700;
 }

 .div_correct {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: blue;
     font-weight: 700;
 }
```

```html
<input id="box" type="hidden" />
<button onclick="wrong_answer()" id="button1">WRONG ANSWER!</button>
<button onclick="correct_answer()">CORRECT ANSWER!</button>
<div id="div1" class="div_wrong"></div>
<div id="div2" class="div_correct"></div>
```

I want to perform a sum total of the list of numbers thus created by this program. What can I add to my program?

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: for example if the list comes out to be 
-1
3
-1
then I want to add up all the elements of this list. Which means I would expect the answer to be 1 in this case.

Comment: You are declaring `calc` inside each function and then using an unnecessary operation on it to assign values to your new divs. Instead declare `calc` once outside both functions to keep the total count, and simply assign the new values directly inside your new divs

Comment: you mean that I should just use "0" instead of defining a variable??

Comment: `0 - (-3) = 3` substracting a negative number will make a number positive.

Comment: @PrabhaanGoyal you are using `calc` for nothing. the result of your operation `calc - calc2` is always `-calc2` so `calc` is pointless as a constant since it's not supposed to be changed or give any value. For the grand total you may perform it in several ways.. even just fetching all the divs you created and sum their content

Comment: but why are you reversing all your logic? Is a correct answer really worth `-3` points?

Comment: or probably `calc` itself should be an argument of your functions as the grand total.. but it's a bit confusing why did you choose to factor your logic that way honestly

Answer (score 1):

You were declaring calc unneccesarily.

```js
let sum = 0;

function wrong_answer() {
  var div_ele = document.createElement("div");
  div_ele.innerHTML = -1;
  sum = sum - 1;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
  document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(div_ele);
}
function correct_answer() {
  var div_ele = document.createElement("div");
  div_ele.innerHTML = 3;
  sum = sum + 3;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
  document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(div_ele);
}
```

```css
.div_wrong {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: red;
     font-weight: 700;
 }

 .div_correct {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: blue;
     font-weight: 700;
 }
```

```html
<input id="box" type="hidden" />
<button onclick="wrong_answer()" id="button1">WRONG ANSWER!</button>
<button onclick="correct_answer()">CORRECT ANSWER!</button>
<div>Sum is: <span id="sum">0</div>
<div id="div1" class="div_wrong"></div>
<div id="div2" class="div_correct"></div>
```

Comment: don't use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), all you need is [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: simple solution but remains the repetitive code. Both functions have a 95% equality.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `totalSum` to display the total sum. And to make the calculation a lot easier, change `wrong_answer()` to `updateTotal(-1)` and `correct_answer()` to `updateTotal(3)`. Create the following script-section to calculate the `totalSum`:

```js
var totalSum = 0;

function updateTotal(change) {
  var div_ele = document.createElement("div");
  div_ele.textContent = change;

  // version: 1
  //if (change > 0) {
  //    div_ele.className = "div_correct";
  //} else {
  //    div_ele.className = "div_wrong";
  //}

  // version: 2
  //div_ele.classList.toggle('div_correct', change > 0);
  //div_ele.classList.toggle('div_wrong', change <= 0);

  // version: 3
  div_ele.classList.add((change > 0) ? 'div_correct' : 'div_wrong');

  totalSum += change;
  document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(div_ele);
  document.getElementById("totalSum").textContent = totalSum;
}
```

```css
.div_wrong {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: "Agency FB";
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.div_correct {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: "Agency FB";
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateTotal(-1)" id="button1">WRONG ANSWER!</button>
<button onclick="updateTotal(3)">CORRECT ANSWER!</button>
<div id="totalSum" class="div_total"></div>
<div id="div1" class="div_wrong"></div>
<div id="div2" class="div_correct"></div>
```

Comment: you should learn to use ternaries (ternary conditional operator) which can shorten the code and make it more readable. `div_ele.className = (change > 0) ? 'div_correct"' : 'div_wrong'`. Last but not least you should add classes not with `className` but `classList` to append classes instead of overwriting. You could also use `toggle()` here to apply classes based on a condition.

Comment: PS: But I like the fact that you only use one function for both buttons!

Comment: @tacoshy it is a brand new div that is having it's initial class assigned, a perfectly valid use of `className`

Comment: @pilchard true but for developing good habits. And `classList.toggle()` could add the class based on the condition directly => simplictiy

Comment: @tacoshy matter of opinion. There is an argument for using the appropriate method for the case, `className` assignment signals initialization, while `add` or `toggle` implies existing classes.

Comment: @tacoshy, thanks for the hint, updated my answer.

Comment: @pilchard, thanks for the hint, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is wrong. It would help if you used a global variable to track the scores. Beyond that, you added unnecessarily repetitive code.

I would advise you to make use of `data` attributes. You can include the score within the data attributes instead of the JS code. This makes the code completely abstractive to which button is clicked.

```js
const BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const OUTPUT = document.querySelector('#sum');
let score = 0;

BUTTONS.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
    // function to calculate scores
    calculateScore(parseInt(element.target.dataset.points));
    
    // function to calculate Counts
    updateCounts(element.target.dataset.value);
  })
});

function calculateScore(points) {
  score = score + points;
  OUTPUT.textContent = score;
}

function updateCounts(value) {
  let element = document.querySelector(`#${value}_answers`);
  element.textContent = parseInt(element.textContent) + 1;
}
```

```css
.div_wrong {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: red;
     font-weight: 700;
 }

 .div_correct {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: "Agency FB";
     color: blue;
     font-weight: 700;
 }
```

```html
<input id="box" type="hidden" />
<button data-points="-1" data-value="wrong">WRONG ANSWER!</button>
<button data-points="3" data-value="correct">CORRECT ANSWER!</button>
<div>
  <label for="sum">The sum is: </label>
  <output id="sum">0</output>
</div>

<output id="wrong_answers" class="div_wrong">0</output>
<output id="correct_answers" class="div_correct">0</output>
```

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of using data attributes, why not go further and use event delegation? Assigning listeners to all buttons is wasteful and lacks granularity. Also, since nitpicking seems to be the order of the day, `querySelector` is less efficient than `getElementById`.

Comment: @pilchard sorry that you feel you have to nitpick. Adding a real event delegation for 2 buttons with no child nodes and no event bubble would overcomplicate an issue for a beginner who will already have a hard time with this answer. There performance difference in this case will be in ns (marginal). I rather go for a unified way of conventions and readbility rather then microing ns performances